# Making Sticky left sided header view in Flutter Grid view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make left sided sticky header view on GridView. Tried some code on the internet and Build below image with the help of this [article](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f).

But the problem is Grid contents are placed below the Header view (see **Header Section 2**).

What I'm trying to achieve is design in the **Header Section 1**. And when scrolling the contents **Header Section 2** should be sticked in the same position of **Section 1**.

> Is there any way to make the design with desired functionality?

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    makeHeader('Header Section 1'),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 90),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    makeHeader('Header Section 2'),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 90),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    makeHeader('Header Section 3'),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 90),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.pink, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.indigo, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 500,
        width: 100,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Making HeaderView Widget:

```
SliverPersistentHeader makeHeader(String headerText) {
 return SliverPersistentHeader(
  pinned: true,
  delegate: SliverAppBarDelegate(
    minHeight: 200.0,
    maxHeight: 200.0,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 325.0),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: Center(child: Text(headerText)),
        ),
        // Spacer(),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

[image]